# Pause Foreach Loop until the first Iteration is completed

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

**This is my scenario:**

```
ClassA
{
  Timer tmr = new Timer(1000);
  void Start()
     {
       tmr.start();
     }

  void tmr_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            //Do Something
            if (myCondition==true)
            {
                //Do Something

                tmr.Stop(); // Or Change Value of a Property! anything that shows it
                            //meets the condition.
            }
        }
}


Class WorkflowController
{
   list<ClassA> allA=new list<ClassA>(){new A1,new A2, new A3}
   void Start()
   {
     foreach(item in allA)
     {
        item.start()
     } 
   }
}
```

**Question:**

Now I want the `foreach loop` to executes `A1.Start()` and wait until the timer meets the condition (here `x>50` and after 50 seconds) and stops. then executes `A2.Start()`  and wait until timer meets the condition and stops again. then executes `A3.Start()` and so on. The `WorkFlowController` controls the Workflow of my Application. I don't know what is the simple way to do it. Shall I make use of `INotifyPropertyChanged`? shall I use `Eventhandler`? or is there a better way?

Comment: I hope this is just example code. For timing (wait X seconds) don't use timers, instead use the `StopWatch` class. For suspending the code from execution while doing anything asynchrone use a `WaitHandle`.

Comment: consider using manual reset events

Comment: Erm, are you using async code to do something synchronous?

Comment: You seem to be trying to reimplement `Task`. This is all done for you already. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an event handler to syncronize it

```
ClassA
{
  ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
  Timer tmr = new Timer(1000);
  void Start()
     {
       tmr.start();
     }

  void tmr_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            x++;
            if (x > 50)
            {
                //Do Something

                tmr.Stop(); // Or Change Value of a Property! anything that shows it
                            //meets the condition.
                mre.Set();
            }
        }

  public void Wait()
  { 
     mre.WaitOne();
  }
}


Class WorkflowController
{
   list<ClassA> allA=new list<ClassA>(){new A1,new A2, new A3}
   void Start()
   {
     foreach(item in allA)
     {
        item.start();
        item.Wait();
     } 
   }
}
```

Comment: by mre.wait() you mean mre.WaitOne()?  cause it doesn't have this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tasks with this follow implementation :

```
List<ClassA> all = new List<ClassA> { ... };
private async void Start()
{
    foreach (var item in all)
    {
         await item.DoWork();
    }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public async Task DoWork()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50000); // wait 50sec
        // Do work            
    }
}
```

You have a ["How to: Wait on One or More Tasks to Complete" here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610.aspx)

Hope it's help !

Comment: The start method is async and should be syncronized too.

Comment: How does foreach loop understands to continue after the DoWork is done? I am using a timer!

Comment: My code is an example to loop on asynchronous method, and wait it's completed before loop again. You can adapt it to your case.

Comment: @JoffreyKern I am really sorry but can you help me implement my code with your way? I really appreciate that

Comment: @JoffreyKern Oooh No! I think you didn't understand the question (or I explained that in a bad way) (x>50) was just a sample code. actually it is a part of a bigger workflow in my application. I just wrote (x>50) for the sake of simplicity. every tick I calculate something until I reach to the point which is needed and then I stop the timer. I don't want to wait just for 50 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
private async void Start()
{
    foreach (var item in all)
    {
         await item.DoWorkAsync();
    }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public async Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        bool done = false;

        while(!done)
        {
            DoStuff();
            DoMoreStuff();

            if(someCondition)
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find Task.Delay() method. are you sure about that?

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh: Namespace "System.Threading.Tasks". You need .NET 4.5 for that (as for async and await). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In practice your code seems no different than.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Task.Wait(Task.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //Do Something
            if (myCondition==true)
            {
                // Do Something
                // Or Change Value of a Property! anything that shows it
                // meets the condition.
            }
        });
}
```